# Cannot access AWS webserver using public IP

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a free AWS account and have set up a EC2 Virtual machine on Windows Server 2008 R2. I use RDP to access the VM.

I have set up XAMPP and deployed my PHP application in it. I can access it through `localhost/myapp` but not using the public IP.

Here's what I have tried so far:

1. Added Inbound rule for HTTP on port 80 in my Security group.
2. Checked Inbound rules on Windows firewall for HTTP port 80. There were 3 of them and inactive. I activated all 3.
3. Checked the port of Apache. Its running on 80.

But no help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you server haves direct access to the wan or it is behind any nework device?

Answer (score 0):

Is this particular instance in a Public or Private subnet?

If a Private subnet, are you traversing a NAT to get Internet access?

If a Public subnet, ensure you have an Internet Gateway attached to your Route Table. Then check your Network ACLs and make sure you do not have an explicity Deny for traffic Inbound to Port 80.